# MongoDB - $filter an array of objects with $exists

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an array of objects and in the `$project` pipeline of MongoDB I have to choose the one element whose metadata does not exist. So, for example below are a few documents after my `$group` pipeline -

```
{
  _id: {
      genre: "suspense",
    },
   price: 10210.6,
   data: [
      {
        subGenre: "Thriller",
        flag: true,
      },
      {
        subGenre: "jumpScare",
      },
      {
        subGenre: "horror",
        flag: true,
      }
    ]
}
```

After this, I need to run a `$project` pipeline where I have to only project that element of the data array where the flag does not exist. My syntax for that is -

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "price": 1,
      "data": {
        "$getField": {
          "field": "subGenre",
          "input": {
            "$first": {
             "$filter": { input: "$data", cond: { "$exists": [ "$$this.flag", false ] } }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But this is throwing an error -

> Invalid $project :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$exists'

The output should be -

```
{
  price: 10210.6,
  subGenre: "jumpScare"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$exists` which is invalid, you can compare the value with:

```
$eq: [
  "$$this.flag",
  undefined
]
```

This aims to check whether the `flag` field does not exist.

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_-koi6oZyfh)

---

You may also work with checking the `$type` value is matched with "missing". (Tested this works in MongoDB Compass)

```
$eq: [
  { $type: "$$this.flag" },
  "missing"
]
```

Comment: This works fine here in thre mongo playground but its not returning any value in my mongodb compass and in my code also in nodejs idk why

Comment: Also why is $exists invalid? Is there any other way instead of these both?

Comment: Updated the answer. `$exists` is a [query operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/), not possible to work in the aggregation pipeline.